# How can I show that an image link is disabled by using both pointer-events and cursor properties?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, pointer-events

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8bjr3eL/)

I have an image wrapped in an anchor that has a click action on it (a simple case is in the above fiddle).

At certain times, this action is not valid, so I would like to do 3 things:

1. grey the image out  (`-webkit-filter: invert(40%);`)
2. disable the click event  (`pointer-events: none;`)
3. change the cursor (`cursor: not-allowed;`)

Greying the image out always works, but it seems like the pointer-events and cursor properties don't play nicely together.

When applying both the pointer-events and cursor properties, I'd expect the action to be disabled AND the cursor to change - but it seems like the pointer-events property overrides my ability to set the cursor.

What's the correct way to do this?

Code:

```
No styles  <br>
<a href="javascript:alert('clicked')"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>
<hr>
pointer-events: none (good - I cannot click) <br>
<a class="grey no-click-1" href="javascript:alert('clicked')"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>
<hr>
cursor: not-allowed (good - I can click, but the cursor has changed) <br>
<a class="grey no-click-2" href="javascript:alert('clicked')"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>
<hr>
pointer-events: none AND cursor: not-allowed (bad - I can't click but the cursor has NOT changed)<br>
<a class="grey no-click-3" href="javascript:alert('clicked')"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>


img {
    height: 80px;
}

.grey {
    -webkit-filter: invert(40%);    
}

.no-click-1 {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.no-click-2 {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.no-click-3 {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: How are you applying the `no-click` class? javascript?

Comment: Actually by using Angular's ng-click attribute, but I'm just trying to give a more simplified case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Set the wrapping `div`s to display: inline-block;

http://jsfiddle.net/o8bjr3eL/4/

Wrap your element in a `div` with the `cursor: not-allowed;` and the child `a` has the `pointer-events: none;`

html:

```
<div class="not-allowed">
        <a class="no-click" href="#"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"/></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** css:

```
.not-allowed{
    cursor: not-allowed;

    display: inline-block; /* This is working */

}
.no-click {
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-filter: invert(40%);
}
```

That worked for me

Comment: Thanks - I did see an example where that works.  Unfortunately the images this applies to are in a non-breaking horizontal line so I don't think I can use a div.  I tried setting setting display:inline on the divs and the behavior reverts to how it is with spans (expected, I guess).

Comment: I edited the fiddle and CSS: display: inline-block seems to work with the divs

Comment: Ah, thanks!  So inline doesn't work, but inline-block does.  Awesome.

Answer (score 3):

The `pointer-events: none` blocks all interaction with the cursor, so the `cursor: not allowed` is never triggered.

Because `pointer-events: none` is not very well supported by IE (http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), I would say it's safer to remove the click behavior in javascript, either via another event listener or when you add the `no-click` class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8bjr3eL/2/) - Fiddle does this with the no-click class, but performance would be better if you can attach one event listener to a wrapper class.

```
$('.wrapper-class').on('click', '.no-click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at something like this.  Fortunately though, this is an internal application where only Chrome needs to be supported.